# Активировать кнопку при выполнении нескольких условий

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox, textbox

Есть два groupBox-a, в каждом из них есть по несколько checkBox-ов и textBox-ов. И есть одна кнопка допустим просто button1. Изначально для кнопки свойство Enabled поставил false. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка становилась активна, только если в groupBox1 ни один из текстбоксов (естественно только активных) не был пустым(допустим если пользователь начал вводить текст или там уже есть какой-то текст) и в groupBox2 любой из чекбоксов был чекнут? Если ни одно условие не выполняется, кнопка должна быть не активной. Если это важно, чеки и боксы (их много) добавлены в массивы chBox и tBox. Да, и мне тоже важно знать, в каком месте нужно поместить этот код или в какое событие добавить? Мне кажется лучше как-то использовать LINQ. Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно вычисление всех Enabled/Disabled состояний происходит относительно быстро -- по сравнению со скоростью изменений идущих от пользователя. Поэтому имеет смысл сделать один метод который вычисляет все эти состояния для всех контролов сразу -- например, `EnableControls()`. Ну и делаете методы-обработчики событий от контролов (клики, выбор элемента), из этих обработчиков вызываем `EnableControls()`. Также вызываете этот метод при загрузке формы.

Ну и метод EnableControls() выглядит примерно так:

```
void EnableControls()
{
   button1.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked || checkBox2.Checked;
   button2.Enabled = ...
}
```